# Pass object to component using material dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a component in which a create and trigger a material design dialog modal:

```
template = `<show-deleted-media-information
    media-item=JSON.stringify(${mediaItem})
    on-delete="vm.deleteMedia()"
    ></show-deleted-media-information>`;

this.$mdDialog
    .show({
        template,
        targetEvent: null,
        clickOutsideToClose: false
    })
```

In the `ShowDeletedMediaInformation` component I want to use that object:

```
bindings: {
    mediaItem: '&',
}

export class ShowDeletedMediaInformation {

    private mediaItem: any;

    constructor(
        private $mdDialog,
    ) {}

    public $onChanges() {
        console.log(this.mediaItem);
    }

    public cancel(): void {
        this.$mdDialog.cancel();
    }
}
```

When I open the dialog I get the following error:

> Unexpected end of expression: JSON.stringify([object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must include all of your code template into brackets

in this way

```
template = `<show-deleted-media-information
    media-item=${JSON.stringify(mediaItem)}
    on-delete="vm.deleteMedia()"
    ></show-deleted-media-information>`;
```

Comment: Ah of course. Thanks. Getting a different error now `Lexer Error: Unterminated quote at columns 94-100 ["Peter] in expression [{"reason":"dsadas","clearing":{"personId":"70741dff-7aeb-41cf-9b9b-3e5baa702745","personName":"Peter] The `clearing` is another array in the mediaItem array. Could there be an issue with a white space? The value is `Peter Boomsma`.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma as error says there are missing quotes, check if every property and values have double quoutes. it looks like the "personName" value does not have termination quote

Comment: It does, there seems to be an issue with it being 2 words. Might need to escape it.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma  try to debug it for example: open a developer tool of Chrome, go to console and define a variable like var jsonValue = <your_json_input> then try to convert with JSON.stringify(jsonValue)

Comment: Not sure what the issue is but I had to add `'` single quotes around `${JSON.stringify(mediaItem)}` that fixed the issue.